# Get value from callback function of API in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Here is a function b(), I need to get the result from it：

```
b(app_key, app_secret,  function (result) {
                      //I can get the value of result here
})
```

And there is a function a() , I can handle the c variable in this function：

```
async a(Other_variables) {
//some code else

c = result+'abc', // I can edit var c here

//some code else
  }
```

I know I can code like this:

```
async a(Other_variables, result) {
//some code else

c = result+'abc', // I can edit var c here

//some code else
  }


b(app_key, app_secret,  function (result) {
 a(Other_variables, result)
})
```

But I don’t want to modify function a(), is there any other solution?

Comment: YOu can make result as global variable

Comment: Confusing and wrong. This returned 4 errors, 7 with colons missing. I cannot follow so I'm not sure you can code like that and effectively.